# Solidity TypeError

Tags: typeerror, solidity, smartcontracts

```
mapping(uint => Info) private infos;

struct Info {
    uint _id;
    address _add;
}

function getInfo(uint _infoid) external view returns (uint, address) {
    return infos[_infoid]; //to return id & add
}
```

I have another function that is creating the mapping using the struct so that's not an issue here.

The error I am facing is in `getInfo()`

```
from solidity:
TypeError: Different number of arguments in return statement than in returns declaration.
  --> Contract.sol:97:9:
   |
97 |         return infos[_infoid];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write this `return infos[_infoid];` you're returning only the object and not its attributes with relative values.
For fix this issue, you must access to the attributes inside the object in this case _id, _add using the statement:

```
[StructObject].[Attribute];
```

You can change your getInfo() method implementation with this:

```
function getInfo(uint _infoid) external view returns (uint, address) {
  return (infos[_infoid]._id, infos[_infoid]._add);
}
```